# How to replace substring?

Tags: java

Given following `String` 
`"ws([WM_10003] , {MD_1402359631813}{MV_200101010000024})"` i need to raplace only `"{MD_1402359631813}"` this value of `""` How  to solve this problem. How to raplace substring?

Comment: please try to make your question more understandable...

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give us much to go on, but based on your question I suspect you forgot to update your String reference. It's as easy as something like this,

```
String str = "ws([WM_10003] , {MD_1402359631813}{MV_200101010000024})";
String toRemove = "{MD_1402359631813}";
System.out.println("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(toRemove, "");
System.out.println("After: " + str);
```

Output is

```
Before: ws([WM_10003] , {MD_1402359631813}{MV_200101010000024})
After: ws([WM_10003] , {MV_200101010000024})
```

Comment: i dont know "{MD_1402359631813}" string, in other words i cant input "{MD_1402359631813}" this string

Comment: if i cut "{MD_1402359631813}" this is so easy

Comment: @user3377124 *i dont know "{MD_1402359631813}" string, in other words i cant input "{MD_1402359631813}" this string.* Did you notice that `String toRemove` above is a variable? What exactly are you trying to do, if not this?

Comment: @user3377124 *if i cut "{MD_1402359631813}" this is so easy?* Is that like cutting the cheese?